# Startup Error: Unable to detect graphics environment; pycharm-community on VM with Ubuntu16.04

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pycharm, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to access pycharm-community from local mac system, which is installed on Google Cloud Engine (VM) with GPU and Ubuntu 16.04 environment. I was installed all the required softwares, but when  I'm trying to access pycharm-community using ssh from my local system I am getting:

"Startup Error: Unable to detect graphics environment".

Installed pycharm-community using below commands:

```
  wget https://storage.googleapis.com/cuda-deb/pycharm-community_2016.3-mm1_all.deb

  sudo dpkg -i pycharm-community_2016.3-mm1_all.deb
```

I am accessing GCE VM from my mac terminal using

```
 ssh -X -i <private key file> <netid>@<External Ip address>
```

I am able to run xclock from terminal and able to display clock after installing 'XQuartz' in my mac.

Still, I am not able to access pycharm IDE from my mac.

Comment: Solved: When I opened with "ssh -Y -i <private key file> <netid>@<External Ip address>" It is working.

Comment: Hi, can you put this as an answer to your own question? It wil lbe more clear for next users that have this problem and end up here. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution to access VM from system using

```
ssh -X -i <private key file> <netid>@<External Ip address>
```

(or)

```
ssh -Y -i <private key file> <netid>@<External Ip address>
```

In my case, 2nd option worked for me.